NOKResponse(error=Unauthorized, description=The device token provided could not be validated against any known credentials)
I had a live app on google play that uses push-notifications system and it was working for quite a long time but recently I noticed that the beams login function that I use to register a user in the pusher isn't working even tho i didnt modify it when i checked the log there was this message spamming

NOKResponse(error=Unauthorized, description=The device token provided could not be validated against any known credentials)

and what's weird is that the same instance id and key are working fine with the iOS version.
here is the code for initializing the pusher.
inside main activity:
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                MALogger.e("Firebase Token exception -> ${task.exception}")
            }else {
                MALogger.e("Firebase Token -> ${task.result}")
            }
        }

        PusherUtils.appSetupAndInterestsSubscription(this)

inside PusherUtils
fun appSetupAndInterestsSubscription(appContext: Context) {
        
        PushNotifications.start(appContext, BuildConfig.pusherInstanceId)
        PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("all-guests-and-users")
        PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("debug-all")
    }

suspend fun loginBeams(
        id: Int,
        apiToken: String,
    ) = suspendCoroutine<Boolean> { continuation ->
        Timber.e("BeamsCallback -> Pre login $apiToken $id\n$BEAMS_TOKEN_URL")


        val tokenProvider = BeamsTokenProvider(
            BEAMS_TOKEN_URL,
            object : AuthDataGetter {
                override fun getAuthData(): AuthData {
                    val headerMap = mapOf(
                        "Authorization" to "Bearer $apiToken"
                    )
                    Timber.e("BeamsCallback -> Pre login $apiToken $id\n$BEAMS_TOKEN_URL")
                    return AuthData(
                        headerMap,
                        emptyMap(),
                    )
                }
            }
        )

        PushNotifications.setUserId(
            "users-${id}",
            tokenProvider,
            object : BeamsCallback<Void, PusherCallbackError> {
                override fun onFailure(error: PusherCallbackError) {
                    Timber.e("BeamsCallback -> Could not login to Beams")
                    Timber.e("BeamsCallback -> Could not login to Beams: ${error.message}")
                    continuation.resume(false)
                }

                override fun onSuccess(vararg values: Void) {
                    Timber.e("BeamsCallback -> Beams login success")

                    continuation.resume(true)
                }
            }
        )
    }

I tried:
reinstalling the app
invalidating cache and restart
stopping and restarting the service
